# Прерывание потока с вечным циклом

Tags: c#, windows, многопоточность

Мне необходимо во время работы утилиты все время слушать порт, и когда на него поступают команды, выполнять определенные действия. Сама утилита у меня реализована в виде формы  `WinForms`, а при ее старте вызывается отдельный поток с вечным циклом. Выглядит все примерно так

```
ServThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServStart));
ServThread.IsBackground = true;
ServThread.Start();
```

и далее уже в этом потоке

```
Listener = new TcpListener(LocalPort);
Listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    TcpClient client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    //что-то делаем...
} //завершили итерацию
```

Проблема вот в чем - если выходить из системы (win7, xp), то просит принудительно завершить программу http://joxi.ru/ZrJE6y8t8lQgAj. По-видимому, из-за вечного цикла. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: ну так проверьте, что поток находиться в состоянии прерывания и сделайте выход. Что то вида if (terminated) return;

Comment: @KoVadim в каком месте проверять? на этой строчке TcpClient client = Listener.AcceptTcpClient(); программа ждет, пока на порт не поступит команда.  Если команд на порт не поступало, оно там так и будет висеть.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Попробуйте асинхронный интерфейс.

```
async Task<TcpClient> AcceptAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (ct.Register(listener.Stop))
    {
        try
        {
            return await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted)
                throw new OperationCanceledExeption();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь вам не нужен отдельный поток, и вы можете писать так:

```
m_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

try
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(LocalPort);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = await AcceptAsync(listener, m_cts.Token);
        //что-то делаем...
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // операция оборвана
}
```

и разумеется

```
void StopListener()
{
    m_cts.Cancel();
}
```

При завершении программы не забудьте вызвать `StopListener`.

Answer (score 4):

Можно попробовать сделать Listener объектом доступным из основного (UI) thread. Когда форма закрывается - вызвать Listener.Server.Close()

Answer (score -1):

сделал отдельным классом:

```
class ServiceWorker
    {
       public TcpListener Listener; // Объект, принимающий TCP-клиентов

                // Thread signal.
    public ManualResetEvent tcpClientConnected;

    public ServiceWorker()
    {
        _shouldStop = false;
        tcpClientConnected = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        // Создаем "слушателя" для указанного порта
        Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6543);
    }

    public void ThreadProc()
    {            
        Listener.Start(); // Запускаем его

        // В бесконечном цикле
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            // Принимаем новых клиентов
            tcpClientConnected.Reset();

            // Accept the connection. 
            // BeginAcceptSocket() creates the accepted socket.
            Listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(
                new AsyncCallback(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback),
                this);
            tcpClientConnected.WaitOne();
        }

        // Остановим "слушателя"
        Listener.Stop();
    }

    // Process the client connection.
    public static void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Get the listener that handles the client request.
        ServiceWorker worker = (ServiceWorker)ar.AsyncState;

        Socket client = worker.Listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
        Client(client);

        // Signal the calling thread to continue.
        worker.tcpClientConnected.Set();
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
        tcpClientConnected.Set();
    }

    private volatile bool _shouldStop;
}
```

управление запуск:

```
private ServiceWorker worker = new ServiceWorker();
Thread t = new Thread(worker.ThreadProc);
 t.Start();
остановка:
worker.RequestStop();
```

Comment: Установка булева флага не прерывает метода `AcceptTcpClient`.

Comment: да действительно пришлось переделать

Answer (score -2):

Более простой вариант "в лоб".
В конце вечного цикла ставить Thread.Sleep(0):

`while (true)`
{
`do_some_job();`

`//Allow other thread to work`
Thread.Sleep(0);
`}`

Comment: Вы даже проблемы не поняли. Проблема не в том, что цикл занимает слишком много времени - напротив, цикл 100% времени спит, и чтобы его прервать - надо сначала поток как-то пробудить.

Comment: У вас while(true) в потоке GUI? Тогда всё правильно, вы не сможете завершить этот поток и винда справедливо будет просить принудительно завершить работу приложения. Вынесите while(true) в отдельный поток, и его уже останавливайте по Form.Closing().

Comment: Да, по поводу "поток спит". Если у вас выполняется сторонняя функция (к примеру - AcceptConnection), то до момента приёма сообщения поток будет не спать (что происходит при Sleep()), а ожидать.

Comment: Нет, у автора цикл в отдельном потоке. Спать, ожидать - какая разница? Важно, что ваше предложение не решает проблемы.